# Grabbing multiple documents with flask-mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I'm using Flask-MongoEngine in my python application, and I'm trying to grab a list of documents WHERE a field equals some value. I know how to grab a single document based on the value of a field using get(name="chris"), but how would I be able to do this with returning multiple documents? Nothing in the docs is really sticking out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoEngine Document classes have an objects attribute, which is used for accessing the objects in the database associated with the class. example:

```
uk_users = User.objects(country='uk')
```

For advanced queries you can use the filter attribute:

```
uk_female_users = User.objects(country='uk').filter(gender='f')
```

This is the related documentation [MongoEngine - Querying the database](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html)